# Need to create stored procedure to copy data from multiple tables to one table

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I only have experience in creating simple custom tables and I haven't done stored procedures before. I would like to know how to create a stored procedure to copy data from multiple tables into one single table.

There are four tables (and a total of 6 columns in these 4 tables) from which I have to copy data to my Main table.

```
Table 1 - C1, C2 = Main table - C1, C2                  
Table 2 - C1, C2 = Main table - C3, C4           
Table 3 - C1, C2 = Main table - C5, C6          
Table 4 - C1, C2 = Main table - C7, C8
```

This way my Main table will have a total of 8 columns with data from other tables, and 4 columns with time-stamp, serial number, and such.

What would be the best way to approach this?

Comment: You don't need a stored procedure for that. And you don't need to make a table that is a copy of other tables

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Tag the question with the database you are using.

Comment: you need a common key (column) between all 4 tables to merge them in 1 row in the main table. Writing a stored proc or an anonymous sql block depends upon the database you are using (which should not be that complicated)

Comment: @e4c5 - Then what would be a better way to do it? An I am not making exact copies of these 4 tables. I'm only trying to get particular columns from these 4 tables and combine it in one Main so that it is easier for referencing purposes. Or at least that is what my task says.

Comment: Hardly enough information to go by. At least show what your tables  look like and mention what your RDBMs vendor is

Comment: @ash I am using oracle on toad. There are no common columns in any of the tables I am trying to get the data from. Is this something that is doable?

Comment: @e4c5 So without seeing the actual table, there is no way for you to answer the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like that (the columns Ci should be nullable):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PROC_COPYTABLE
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO MAIN(C1, C2) SELECT C1, C2 FROM T1 
    INSERT INTO MAIN(C3, C4) SELECT C1 as C3, C2 as C4 FROM T2
    INSERT INTO MAIN(C5, C6) SELECT C1 as C5, C2 as C6 FROM T3
    INSERT INTO MAIN(C7, C8) SELECT C1 as C7, C2 as C8 FROM T4 
END
```